# How to rectify segmentation fault?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

The program bellow displays the error: "segmentation fault(core dumped)".

It should display the flat file record using vector, read the record each line and get the field's and push back into the vector r_record. And push back into the table.

```
//.. includes
#define LIMIT 72
#define FIELD 25

using namespace std;
typedef vector <string> record_t;
typedef vector <record_t> table_t;
char line[FIELD];   
string s_field;
table_t table;
record_t r_record;

void getField(char s[LIMIT])
{
    char field[LIMIT];      
    int i=0;
    r_record.clear();
    while(s[i]  != '\n')
    {   
        if (s[i] != '\t' )
        {                                                       
            field[i] = s[i];
            //*s_field = *s_field+1;        
        }               
        i++;
    }
    s_field = field;            
    r_record.push_back(s_field);
} 

void getLine(FILE *fp)
{
    char c;
    int j=0;    
    table.clear();
    l1:while ( (c = getc(fp)) != EOF ) 
    {  
        if( c != '\n' )
        {
           line[j] = c;

        }
        j++;
    }   
    getField(line);
    table.push_back(r_record);
    if(c != EOF)
        goto l1;                        
    cout<<table.size(); 
} 

int main()
{
    double total_time;  
    clock_t start, end;
    start = clock();//time count starts 
    FILE *f1;   
    f1 = fopen("somesamplefile.txt","r+");      
    getLine(f1); 

    end = clock();//time count stops 
    total_time = ((double) (end - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC; //calulate total time
    printf("\nTime taken to print  %f\n", total_time);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It would be best to show an example of the input causing the crash.  Have you run the program in a debugger?

Comment: check `if ( f1 == NULL ) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);` before doing `getLine(f1);`

Comment: `char c;` should be `int c;` otherwise the EOF loop doesn't work

Comment: `getLine` causes buffer overflow, it needs to stop before reaching LIMIT. `getField` also needs to stop before reaching LIMIT.  You could avoid these issues by using `std::string` and `std::getline`.

Comment: if i used std::string how to get the field and the line number that should done by without using fstream

Answer (score 0):

I would pay attention to the comment by @MattMcNabb about checking the limits before assigning values to the individual characters in the strings.

In addition, you haven't null terminated `field` in `getField`. Without that, the statement

```
    s_field = field;
```

is likely to access data out of bounds and cause undefined behavior.

```
void getField(char s[LIMIT])
{
    // **** CORRECTION *****
    // I am guessing you meant to use field[FIELD].
    // char field[LIMIT];      
    char field[FIELD];

    int i=0;
    r_record.clear();

    // **** CORRECTION *****
    // Add a check to stop going beyond the limits of the array.
    // while(s[i]  != '\n')
    while( i < FIELD-1 && s[i]  != '\n')
    {   
        if (s[i] != '\t' )
        {                                                       
            field[i] = s[i];
            //*s_field = *s_field+1;        
        }               
        i++;
    }

    // **** CORRECTION *****
    // Add this
    field[i] = '\0';

    s_field = field;            
    r_record.push_back(s_field);
}
```

Also, I think you meant to use

```
char line[LIMIT];
```

instead of

```
char line[FIELD];
```

Comment: I have replaced your code but it prints one record only but flat contains 100000 records

Answer (score 0):

heartly 001 25  city1
heartly 002 26  city1
heartly 003 27  city1
heartly 004 25  city1
heartly 005 28  city1
heartly 006 29  city1
heartly 007 30  city1
heartly 001 25  city1
heartly 002 26  city1
heartly 003 27  city1

in the text have tab delimited  format that should display not correctly

program after the correction

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include <cstdio>
#include <ctime>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <iterator>
#include <exception>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <map>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <sys/timeb.h>
#include <stdexcept>                                                     // std::out_of_range
#include <time.h>
#define LIMIT 22
#define FIELD 8

using namespace std;
typedef vector <string> record_t;
typedef vector <record_t> table_t;
char line[LIMIT];   
string s_field;
table_t table;
record_t r_record;

vector <string>::iterator t_record;

void getField(char s[LIMIT])
{
    // **** CORRECTION *****
    // I am guessing you meant to use field[FIELD].
    // char field[LIMIT];      
    char field[FIELD];

    int i=0;
    r_record.clear();

    // **** CORRECTION *****
    // Add a check to stop going beyond the limits of the array.
    // while(s[i]  != '\n')
    while( i < FIELD-1 && s[i]  != '\n')
    {   
        if (s[i] != '\t' )
        {                                                       
            field[i] = s[i];
            //*s_field = *s_field+1;        
        }               
        i++;
    }

    // **** CORRECTION *****
    // Add this
    field[i] = '\0';

    s_field = field;            
    r_record.push_back(s_field);    
} 

void getLine(FILE *fp)
{
    char c;
    int j=0;    
    table.clear();
    l1:while ( j < LIMIT-1 ) 
    {  
        c = getc(fp);
        if( c != '\n' )
        {
           line[j] = c;
            j++;
        }                 
    }   
    line[j] = '\0';
    if( c!= EOF )    
    {       
        getField(line);
        table.push_back(r_record);
        j=0;
        goto l1;
    }

} 

int main()
{
    double total_time;  
    clock_t start, end;
    start = clock();//time count starts 
    FILE *f1;   
    f1 = fopen("somesamplefile.txt","r+");      
    getLine(f1); 
    for(t_record = r_record.begin(); t_record != r_record.end(); ++t_record )
    {
      cout <<*t_record <<endl;
    }
    cout<<table.size(); 
    end = clock();//time count stops 
    total_time = ((double) (end - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC; //calulate total time
    printf("\nTime taken to print  %f\n", total_time);

    return 0;
}
```